# Rails4 polymorphic how to use in html page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I used Rails-4.2.8.

Now I had `question` `article` `comments` models, on question has many comments, or one article has many comments, but now how could I submit the `comment` in `question` `show.html.erb`?

**My`models` as follows：**

```
#comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end

#question.rb
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :comments, :as => :commentable, :dependent => :destroy
 end
```

**My `question` `show.html.erb` as follows：**

```
<% @comment = @question.comments.build  %>
<%= form_for([@comment.commentable,@comment]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :content,class: "editormd-markdown-textarea" %>
    <%= f.submit "submit", class: "btn btn-primary pull-right" %>
<% end %>
```

**My `questions_controller.rb` as follows：**

```
def create
   Question.find(params[:question_id]).comments.build
end
```

**My `roots.rb` as follows**

```
resources :questions do
    resources :comments
  end
```

But I got this error, could someone give me some suggests that where I had the wrong codes? Thanks so much!

```
Routing Error
uninitialized constant CommentsController
```

[image]

And also:

```
Request
Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"/MIczvX+UVpMnKx9K2/7cTmoiM1oDcYZO63RE10mDAlnRMJRukFq/2t24yBqfDIg8D1/Midk3FU1IOaTW4twuA==",
 "comment"=>{"content"=>"adfadfadfadfadfdafadf"},
 "comment-editormd-html-code"=>"<p>adfadfadfadfadfdafadf</p>\r\n",
 "commit"=>"Submit",
 "question_id"=>"1"}
```

Comment: is It a typo question_controller.rb(singular) ? and your routes.rb file has resource questions(plural)

Comment: Sorry about that , you are right , thank you @Shani. I had edited again.

Comment: it would be much easy if you could put the whole stack trace of the error

Comment: How could I put the whole stack trace? Sorry that I'm the novice of the rails . Could you give me some example or show me some of the relative documents? @Shani. Thanks very much .

Comment: What else do you see above the Routing Error?

Comment: `Routing Error `
`uninitialized constant CommentsController`
`Rails.root: /Users/hs/Desktop/udask`

`Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Routes`
`Routes match in priority from top to bottom` I got this errors.

Comment: I had uploaded the error.png to the question. Could yout have a look?

Comment: Is it possible that you need to namespace the `form_for` to find the `Admin::ComenntsController` (which seems present in your routes) instead of the `CommentsController` ?

`form_for([:admin, @comment])`

Comment: Thanks , @xlembouras , But It doesn't work also...

Answer (score 0):

try following fix

```
<%= form_for [@comment.commentable,@comment], url: "#{polymorphic_path(commentable)}/comments" do |f| %>
```